# JAXB Unmarshal - Elements missing and elements in not in order

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I am trying to unmarshal an XML that I marshalled before.

In the unmarshalled result, I am missing elements and the elements I get are not in the same order as the input XML. I've created a afterUnmarshal() listener and I see the elements there, but not in the resulting Java Object.

The XSD is structured like this (a 'fanout'-node, for example, can contain another set of processSteps, so it can be deeply nested (tree)):

```
<xsd:element name="process">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Integration Process</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
        <!-- more -->
                <xsd:element name="itinerary" type="lwis:itineraryType"/>
        <!-- more -->
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="itineraryType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="step" type="lwis:stepType"/>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element name="step" type="lwis:stepType"/>
                <xsd:element name="fanout" type="lwis:fanoutType"/>
                <xsd:element name="decision">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                            <!-- snip.. -->
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

I suppose the order is given by the SAX parser, but I can't imagine a SAX parser would change the order for no reason? At the moment, the first element in the list is the last one in the XML. The second element in the list is the third in the XML - it seems random..

Thanks for any help!

Sample Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<process name="My.Process" description="My Process description" qualityOfService="AT_LEAST_ONCE" entryEndpoint="ENTRY.EP" xmlns="http://www.xxxxx.com/ns/yyyy">
    <faultEndpoint endpoint_ref="EXIT.EP"/>
    <rejectEndpoint endpoint_ref="EXIT.EP"/>
    <itinerary>
        <step name="Step 1" endpoint_ref="Step1.EP" type="SERVICE"/>
        <step name="Step2-CBRStep" endpoint_ref="Step2.EP" type="SERVICE"/>
        <decision name="Decision-nonameneeded">
            <option name="op1">
                <step name="Step 2A" endpoint_ref="Step2a.EP" type="SERVICE"/>
            </option>
            <option name="op2">
                <step name="Step 2B" endpoint_ref="Step2a.EP" type="SERVICE"/>
            </option>
        </decision>
        <step name="Step 3" endpoint_ref="Step3.EP" type="SERVICE"/>
        <fanout name="Fan1">
            <path>
                <step name="Step4A" endpoint_ref="Step4A.EP" type="SERVICE"/>
            </path>
            <path>
                <step name="Step4B" endpoint_ref="Step4B.EP" type="SERVICE"/>
                <step name="Step5" endpoint_ref="Step5.EP" type="SERVICE"/>
            </path>
        </fanout>
        <step name="Step6" endpoint_ref="Step6.EP" type="SERVICE"/>
    </itinerary>
</process>
```

Object:

```
Process Object has a field with itinerary of Type ItineraryType which:
step = StepType ("Step6" from XML)
stepOrFanoutOrDecision = ArrayList:
 item 0: ItineraryType$Decision ("Decision-nonameneeded" from XML)
   option 0: "op1" from XML
     step: "Step 2A" from XML
   option 1: "op2" from XML
     step: "Step 2B" from XML
 item 1: FanoutType ("Fan1" from XML)
     path 0: 
      step: Step4A
     path 1: 
      step: Step5
```

Step 1, Step2-CBRStep and Step 4B is missing?

I have the toString() output of the itinerary here:

```
com.x.ItineraryType@fe39ebf[step=com.x.StepType@28cb15bf[endpointRef=Step6.EP, type=SERVICE, params=<null>, paramsRef=<null>, name=Step6, description=<null>], stepOrFanoutOrDecision={com.x.ItineraryType$Decision@2d00c385[option={com.x.ItineraryType$Decision$Option@d2467d8[step=com.x.StepType@511d9ca5[endpointRef=Step2a.EP, type=SERVICE, params=<null>, paramsRef=<null>, name=Step 2A, description=<null>], stepOrFanoutOrDecision=<null>, name=op1],com.x.ItineraryType$Decision$Option@6f173e3d[step=com.x.StepType@5ef74fc5[endpointRef=Step2a.EP, type=SERVICE, params=<null>, paramsRef=<null>, name=Step 2B, description=<null>], stepOrFanoutOrDecision=<null>, name=op2]}, name=Decision-nonameneeded, description=<null>],com.x.FanoutType@3e963f38[path={com.x.FanoutType$Path@7a1095a1[step=com.x.StepType@56cfbba2[endpointRef=Step4A.EP, type=SERVICE, params=<null>, paramsRef=<null>, name=Step4A, description=<null>], stepOrFanoutOrDecision=<null>, name=<null>],com.x.FanoutType$Path@6027b534[step=com.x.StepType@4ee99a3d[endpointRef=Step5.EP, type=SERVICE, params=<null>, paramsRef=<null>, name=Step5, description=<null>], stepOrFanoutOrDecision=<null>, name=<null>]}, name=Fan1, description=<null>]}]
```

Ant Script I'm using: with extensions hashCode, toString and equals:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="RunningXjc" default="generate-sources" basedir=".">
    <description>Runs Xjc Binding Compiler</description>

    <target name="generate-sources">
        <taskdef name="xjc" classname="org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="buildLib/jaxb-ri-2.2.6/lib">
                    <include name="*" />
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="buildLib/jaxb2-basics-dist-0.6.4/dist">
                    <include name="jaxb2-basics-ant-*.jar" />
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>

        <!-- Generate the Java code for XSD -->
        <xjc destdir="${basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc" extension="true">
            <arg
                line="
        -Xequals
        -XhashCode
        -XtoString
        -Xcopyable
        -Xmergeable" />
            <binding dir="${basedir}/src">
                <include name="**/*.xjb" />
            </binding>
            <schema dir="${basedir}/schema">
                <include name="processSlim.xsd" />
            </schema>
            <!-- Plugins -->
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${basedir}/buildLib/jaxb2-basics-dist-0.6.4">
                    <!-- JAXB2 Basics library -->
                    <include name="dist/jaxb2-basics-*.jar" />
                    <!-- JAXB2 Basics library dependencies -->
                    <include name="dist/jaxb2-basics-runtime-*.jar" />
                    <include name="dist/jaxb2-basics-tools-*.jar" />
                    <include name="lib/commons-beanutils-*.jar" />
                    <include name="lib/commons-lang-*.jar" />
                    <include name="lib/commons-logging-*.jar" />
                    <include name="lib/javaparser-*.jar" />
                    <include name="lib/annox-*.jar" />
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </xjc>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: What does the corresponding JAXB object look like?

Comment: I added a more info - I was hoping to attract your attention :), I read some entries on your blog, couldn't find what I was looking for though..

Comment: Did you generate your model from the XML schema?

Comment: Yes. I'm using an ant script pretty much the same (different version of libs) as seen here: http://marxsoftware.blogspot.ch/2011/08/adding-common-methods-to-jaxb-generated.html

Comment: Could this have something to do with the extensions I am using? Do you have any pointers on how to debug this? (i'm fairly new to jaxb)

Comment: Which extensions are you using?  I haven't had a chance to did into your question yet.

Comment: I'm using toString, hashCode and equals from jaxb2-basics.
I added the ant script to the question, maybe the issue is there..
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't have the solution yet, but I have posted an "answer' explaining why the problem is happening:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15618587/383861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEM**

**From Your XML Schema**

Below is a fragment from your XML schema.  The `itineraryType` contains a sequence where a `step` element can occur both inside and outside of the choice structure.

```xml
<xsd:complexType name="itineraryType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="step" type="lwis:stepType" />
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="step" type="lwis:stepType" />
            <xsd:element name="fanout" type="lwis:fanoutType" />
            <xsd:element name="decision">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <!-- snip.. -->
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

**ItineraryType**

This is causing the `step` element to be mapped to two different properties which is causing your problem.

```java
public class ItineraryType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected StepType step;
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "step", type = StepType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "fanout", type = FanoutType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "decision", type = ItineraryType.Decision.class)
    })
    protected List<Object> stepOrFanoutOrDecision;

   ...
}
```

---

**SOLUTION**

You can use the [simple binding mode](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#simple) extension in the JAXB XJC tool to support this use case.  It will automatically prevent the `step` property from being created.  You can specify this via an external binding document like the following:

**bindings.xml**

```xml
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
    version="2.1">


    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:simple />
    </jxb:globalBindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

Below is how the external bindings file is referenced in an XJC call.  You will need to also use the `-extension` flag to enable the XJC extension to be used.

```
xjc -extension -b bindings.xml schema.xsd
```

Comment: Thanks. So would you say this is a limit of JAXB? It's essentially a tree with 3 kind of nodes which can contain the same nodes, but the first node of each branch must be of type 'step'.
What would you do? (I'm free to chose any other approach (frameworks etc.))

Comment: @PhilW - I have updated my answer with how this can be handled with an built in XJC extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried this and it makes my code easier to read and write. Although it is now also possible to create an object which is not valid according the XSD (first item in process itinerary must be of type step and not decision or fanout). I'm sure you are aware of this, but I thought this might be of interest for others.
Thanks again, you've saved my a couple of days of work, I think.